# How to fill in missing entries by looking at nearest top filled entry in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `Dataframe`:

```
index col1
1     "a"
2
3     "b"
4
5
```

And from that I want to produce the following `Dataframe`:

```
index col1
1     "a"
2     "a"
3     "b"
4     "b"
5     "b"
```

I tried duplicating the dataframe and doing lookup, but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) for missing values and forward filling top values:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].replace('', np.nan).ffill()
```